# Unstable results from Bayesian statistical approach(pymc3)

Tags: python, pandas, bayesian, pymc3

Studying Bayesian statistical approach I have found that my model gives unstable results. I have made a lot of experiments with different samplers(Metropolis and NUTS) and model parameters - tune and draws. Apart from the fact that I know the correct answer I used also autocorrplot and Acceptance Rate test for model trace to check my results. Could you explain please what is wrong - how can I trust this approach if I have what I see. Below is my data and code:

```
%matplotlib inline
from IPython.core.pylabtools import figsize
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
figsize(11, 9)

import scipy.stats as stats
import pymc3 as pm
import theano.tensor as tt
import random
import pandas as pd

count_data = [ 13.        ,  24.        ,   8.        ,  24.        ,
         7.        ,  35.        ,  14.        ,  11.        ,
        15.        ,  11.        ,  22.        ,  22.        ,
        11.        ,  57.        ,  11.        ,  19.        ,
        29.        ,   6.        ,  19.        ,  12.        ,
        22.        ,  12.        ,  18.        ,  72.        ,
        32.        ,   9.        ,   7.        ,  13.        ,
        19.        ,  23.        ,  27.        ,  20.        ,
         6.        ,  17.        ,  13.        ,  10.        ,
        14.        ,   6.        ,  16.        ,  15.        ,
         7.        ,   2.        ,  15.        ,  15.        ,
        19.        ,  70.        ,  49.        ,   7.        ,
        53.        ,  22.        ,  21.        ,  31.        ,
        19.        ,  11.        ,  18.        ,  20.        ,
        12.        ,  35.        ,  17.        ,  23.        ,
        17.        ,   4.        ,   2.        ,  31.        ,
        30.        ,  13.        ,  27.        ,   0.        ,
        39.        ,  37.        ,   5.        ,  14.        ,
        13.        ,  22.        ,  44.99931616,  55.99931616,
        39.99931616,  55.99931616,  38.99931616,  66.99931616,
        45.99931616,  42.99931616,  46.99931616,  42.99931616,
        53.99931616,  53.99931616,  42.99931616,  88.99931616,
        42.99931616,  50.99931616,  60.99931616,  37.99931616,
        50.99931616,  43.99931616,  53.99931616,  43.99931616,
        49.99931616, 103.99931616,  63.99931616,  40.99931616,
        38.99931616,  44.99931616,  50.99931616,  54.99931616,
        58.99931616,  51.99931616,  37.99931616,  48.99931616,
        44.99931616,  41.99931616,  45.99931616,  37.99931616,
        47.99931616,  46.99931616]

figsize(12.5, 3.5)
n_count_data = len(count_data)
plt.bar(np.arange(n_count_data), count_data, color="#348ABD")
plt.xlabel("Time (days)")
plt.ylabel("count of text-msgs received")
plt.title("Did the user's texting habits change over time?")
plt.xlim(0, n_count_data);

with pm.Model() as model:
    alpha = 1.0/count_data.mean()  # Recall count_data is the
                                   # variable that holds our txt counts
    lambda_1 = pm.Exponential("lambda_1", alpha)
    lambda_2 = pm.Exponential("lambda_2", alpha)
    lambda_3 = pm.Exponential("lambda_3", alpha)
    
    tau1 = pm.DiscreteUniform("tau1", lower=0, upper=n_count_data - 1)
    tau2 = pm.DiscreteUniform("tau2", lower=0, upper=n_count_data - 1)
    
    idx = np.arange(n_count_data) # Index
    lambda_ = pm.math.switch(tau2 >= idx, pm.math.switch(tau1 >= idx, lambda_1, lambda_2), lambda_3)
    observation = pm.Poisson("obs", lambda_, observed=count_data)
    
    #step = pm.NUTS()
    trace = pm.sample(5000, tune=20000)#,step=step)
    
lambda_1_samples = trace['lambda_1']
lambda_2_samples = trace['lambda_2']
lambda_3_samples = trace['lambda_3']
tau_samples1 = trace['tau1']
tau_samples2 = trace['tau2']

figsize(16.5, 12)
#histogram of the samples:

lambda_all = np.hstack([lambda_1_samples, lambda_2_samples, lambda_3_samples])
tau_all = np.hstack([tau_samples1, tau_samples2])

la_min = np.min(lambda_all) - 1
la_max = np.max(lambda_all) + 1
ta_min = np.min(tau_all) - 1
ta_max = np.max(tau_all) + 1

ax = plt.subplot(511)
ax.set_autoscaley_on(False)

plt.hist(lambda_1_samples, histtype='stepfilled', bins=30, alpha=0.85,
         label="posterior of $\lambda_1$", color="#A60628", density=True)
plt.legend(loc="upper left")
plt.title(r"""Posterior distributions of the variables
    $\lambda_1,\;\lambda_2,\;\lambda_3,\;\tau1,\;\tau2$""")
plt.xlim([la_min, la_max])
plt.xlabel("$\lambda_1$ value")

ax = plt.subplot(512)
ax.set_autoscaley_on(False)
plt.hist(lambda_2_samples, histtype='stepfilled', bins=30, alpha=0.85,
         label="posterior of $\lambda_2$", color="#7A68A6", density=True)
plt.legend(loc="upper left")
plt.xlim([la_min, la_max])
plt.xlabel("$\lambda_2$ value")

ax = plt.subplot(513)
ax.set_autoscaley_on(False)
plt.hist(lambda_3_samples, histtype='stepfilled', bins=30, alpha=0.85,
         label="posterior of $\lambda_3$", color="#7A68A6", density=True)
plt.legend(loc="upper left")
plt.xlim([la_min, la_max])
plt.xlabel("$\lambda_3$ value")

plt.subplot(514)
w = 1.0 / tau_samples1.shape[0] * np.ones_like(tau_samples1)
plt.hist(tau_samples1, bins=2*len(np.unique(tau_samples1)), alpha=1,
         label=r"posterior of $\tau1$",
         color="#467821", weights=w, rwidth=2.)
plt.xticks(np.arange(n_count_data))

plt.legend(loc="upper left")
plt.ylim([0, 1.0])
plt.xlim([35, len(count_data)-20])
plt.xlabel(r"$\tau1$ (in days)")

plt.subplot(515)
w = 1.0 / tau_samples2.shape[0] * np.ones_like(tau_samples2)
plt.hist(tau_samples2, bins=2*len(np.unique(tau_samples2)), alpha=1,
         label=r"posterior of $\tau2$",
         color="#467821", weights=w, rwidth=2.)
plt.xticks(np.arange(n_count_data))

plt.legend(loc="upper left")
plt.ylim([0, 1.0])
plt.xlim([35, len(count_data)-20])
plt.xlabel(r"$\tau2$ (in days)")
plt.ylabel("probability");

with model:
  _ = pm.plots.autocorrplot(trace,figsize=(17,15))

accept = np.sum(trace['tau1'][1:] != trace['tau1'][:-1])
print("Acceptance Rate for tau1: ", accept/trace['tau1'].shape[0])

accept = np.sum(trace['tau2'][1:] != trace['tau2'][:-1])
print("Acceptance Rate for tau2: ", accept/trace['tau2'].shape[0])

accept = np.sum(trace['lambda_1'][1:] != trace['lambda_1'][:-1])
print("Acceptance Rate for lambda_1: ", accept/trace['lambda_1'].shape[0])

accept = np.sum(trace['lambda_2'][1:] != trace['lambda_2'][:-1])
print("Acceptance Rate for lambda_2: ", accept/trace['lambda_2'].shape[0])

accept = np.sum(trace['lambda_3'][1:] != trace['lambda_3'][:-1])
print("Acceptance Rate for lambda_3: ", accept/trace['lambda_3'].shape[0])
```

Comment: Can you describe your model and what you are trying to accomplish with it?

Comment: Additionally your code doesn't work. I proposed a fix (count_data = np.array([... ), but for unknown reason it was rejected. Please fix it yourself.

Comment: This seems like a sampling issue. For example, trace plots show that the `tau`s tend to lock into their initial values, indicating a high rejection rate in the Metropolis step. I would try experimenting with reparameterizing, though I'm not exactly sure what would be best. Otherwise, you need to use Metropolis only (no NUTS) and sample long enough that the chains actually explore the `tau` space.